# Python - match dictionary value within string & print key in string order

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I asked a similar question to this earlier on but Im still having a hard time figuring this out. I have the following code:

```
d = {'k' : '10', 'a' : '20', 'r' : '30', 'p' : '401'}

string = '401203010'

text = ''

for i, j in d.items():
    if j in string:
        text += i

print(text) #prints karp
```

desired output: `park`

the output I get is `karp`, however I would like the output to be in order of value match in the string, Thanks!

Comment: The dictionaries are not guaranteed to be in order in python. The `j` values in each iteration you are getting are `10 20 30 40` which corresponds to `k a r p` when concatenated together gives you `karp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this maybe?

```
d = {'k' : '10', 'a' : '20', 'r' : '30', 'p' : '40'}

string = '40203010'

text = ''

keylen = len(''.join(d.keys()))

while len(text) != keylen:
    found_val = 0
    for i, j in d.items():
        jl = len(j)
        if string[:jl] == j:
            text += i
            string = string[jl:]
            found_val += 1
    if found_val == 0:
        break

print(text)
```

for the sake of clarity, this is really not an algorithm you want to use here. For example one of the downfalls is if it isn't guaranteed that a part of the string will be in the dictionary values then the loop will never end. I don't want to spend the mental resources to fix that potential pitfall because I have some reading to do but perhaps you can figure out a way around it.

**edit**, never mind that wasn't that difficult but you should test various edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could first split up `string` into substrings of 2, and then switch the keys ad values of `d` in a temporary dictionary, then just add the values from that:

```
d = {'k' : '10', 'a' : '20', 'r' : '30', 'p' : '40'}

string = '40203010'

text = ''

split_string = [string[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(string), 2)]
# ['40', '20', '30', '10']

new_dict = dict((y,x) for x,y in d.items())
# {'30': 'r', '10': 'k', '20': 'a', '40': 'p'}

text = "".join(new_dict[string] for string in split_string)

print(text)
# park
```

Comment: thanks! but not all numbers in the string are 2 digits long, i have re-edited my queston

Comment: Alright, I made this answer based on what you provided.

Comment: Essentially, this works only when it's 2-digit numbers according to the question provided before the edit

Comment: It does! sorry I wasn't clear in the first place, I appreciate your answer